# Display functionality wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my sudoku solver, i'm working to have a good display but i have a problem

at the moment i've this:

```
def show_sudoku(sudoku):
    for i, row in enumerate(sudoku, 1):
        print("|".join(row))
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print("-"*17)
    print("")
```

so for now, it's look like this :

```
111 111 111
111 111 111
111 111 111
-----------
111 111 111
```

that's perfect like this.

now, in fact i want this '|' every 3 column so i've tried like this :

```
print('|'.join(row[i:i+3] for i in range(0, 9, 3)))
```

but i have:

```
"TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"
```

What is wrong exactly? How can i corrige this?

```
111|111|111
111|111|111
111|111|111
-----------
111|111|111
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets to create a list comprehension:

```
print('|'.join([row[i:i+3] for i in range(0, 9, 3)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("|".join([str(i) for i in row])
```